# Positioned inside Stack inside Flexible causes RenderBox error -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Row` with `Flexible` Widgets inside. Inside of one of the Flexibles i need to use `Stack`. But when i use `Positioned` inside of the Stack Widget it causes a `size.isFinite: is not true` error.

Here is an example how the row looks like:
[image]

And here is how the Stack Widget with the positioned widgets should look like:
[image]

every green circle should be one `Positioned`.

I don't want to use a fixed height because i want to keep it responsive.

This is my code:

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  flex: 33,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('?'),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 70,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('?'),
        ),
      ),

    ],
  ),
),
```

The parent of the Flexible ist a Row Widget.